# Apache Not Running - Xampp

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp, windows-8

I'm using Xampp and for some reason Apache will not run. I'm using version 1.8.1 of Xampp.

When I run xampp I get told to check the Windows Event Log or Error.log however there is nothiung regarding any application in there with a error.

I checked that port 88 isn't in use and it isn't.

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

I'm using Windows 8 32BIT. Xampp 1.8.1

Comment: As Xampp is typically a developer too and not something that should be considered production ready your question id off topic for serverfault. As a tool typically used bu programmers it may be on topic for [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for. It may also be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but again please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the command prompt/line in *Admin mode* (Press WinLogo and X, at the desktop; or find cmd.exe and right-click it, then Run as admin) and execute -

```
httpd -t
httpd -k start
```

The above will test the configuration and attempt to start Apache, if there are issues, it should print out some errors and we can trace the problem.

I don't know if Xampp runs on Windows 8 yet, but there are some other WAMPs you might want to look into - WampServer, UniformServer, WampDeveloper Pro (will run on Windows 8 but READ the download page).

> I checked that port 88 isn't in use and it isn't.

If that's not a typo, it's port 80 (and 443 for HTTPS) instead.